# looking for support ticket data set with tickets and answers

Tags: data-request

Im searching for a dataset which contains support tickets and the corresponding answers

I did found various datasets with support ticket questions like
this  [support ticket dataset](https://github.com/pankajkishore/Cognitive-Project/blob/master/latest_ticket_data.csv) but the answers are missing

Answer (score 1):

Kaggle seems to have a number of them.

- [Quantitative measured response](https://www.kaggle.com/sudhanshu746/analyze-helpdesk-tickets)
- [Ticket classification](https://www.kaggle.com/aniketg11/supportticketsclassification)

And Google [has a few more](https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/search?query=support%20ticket&docid=L2cvMTFqY2t2OTd5Mg%3D%3D).

Comment: thanks for the post, unfortunately they only contain the tickets without the provided answers/solutions

Comment: Hi @Sator. Did you find anything? I'm also searching for open dataset of costumer support with answers included.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a StackOverflow dataset for example, from the SuperUser section?

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/stackoverflow/stackoverflow